# I don't know how to activate the phone button to go back without appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, back-button, flutter-onpressed

I created a flutter webview, but when I try to go back to the previous page the app closes. How can I activate the back key on the phone? I would like to use the phone key without adding any more. I thought about using Onbackpressed but in flutter it is not possible. Or you can use Willpopscope () but it doesn't work for me, someone help me please!!

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your case

Comment: this package will help https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your app in scaffold and implement onWillPop feature for scaffold.